# Accessing function from multiple forms on same page

Tags: function, reusability

I have the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            // start a counter for new row IDs
            // by setting it to the number
            // of existing rows
            var newRowNum = 2;

            // bind a click event to the "Add" link
            $('#addnew').click(function() {
                // increment the counter
                newRowNum += 1;

                // get the entire "Add" row --
                // "this" refers to the clicked element
                // and "parent" moves the selection up
                // to the parent node in the DOM
                var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

                // copy the entire row from the DOM
                // with "clone"
                var newRow = addRow.clone();

                // set the values of the inputs
                // in the "Add" row to empty strings
                //$('input', addRow).val('');
                //$('name', addRow).val('os' + newRowNum);

                // replace the HTML for the "Add" link 
                // with the new row number
                $('td:first-child', newRow).html('<input type="hidden" name="on' + newRowNum + '" value="Email Address ' + (newRowNum - 1) + '">Recipient');

                // insert a remove link in the last cell
                $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">Remove<\/a>');

                // loop through the inputs in the new row
                // and update the ID and name attributes

                $('input:hidden', newRow).attr('id','on' + newRowNum ).attr('name','on' + newRowNum );
                $('input:text', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );

                // insert the new row into the table
                // "before" the Add row
                addRow.before(newRow);
                document.tp01.quantity.value = newRowNum-1;
                // add the remove function to the new row
                $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    return false;               
                });

                // prevent the default click
                return false;
            });
        });

        </script>
```

This function is called by clicking on a link in a form (this function adds or removes rows from a table). The link looks like this:

```
<a id="addnew" href="">Add</a>
```

I need to put more forms on the same page accessed by a link in each of those forms that is, as far as the user is concerned, exactly the same as the one shown above. Can someone make suggestions as to how I can reuse the same function to accomplish this?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

move the embedded script to an external JS file:

```
var newRowNum = 2;

var bindLink = function(linkSelector)
{
    // bind a click event to the "Add" link
    $(linkSelector).click(function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in place of the embedded script put a call to bindLink('#addnew') in your ready handler.

Comment: So, to be clear about this, I move the current script from embedded to external ( I was going to do this eventually but, it should not make any difference if it is embedded or external, should it?). I then put the above code in the external JS script as well? Or do I add what you have above to the current script?

Dave

Comment: I would embed the call to bindLink(), as the id ('#id') passed for each link would be different.  I suppose you could give every link the same id, then you could move the bindLink call to the external script as well.

Comment: Also to clarify: the old function was called with a simple <a id="addnew" href="">Add</a> Do I now need to do an onclick="javascript ..." or can I call it with <a id="addnew" href="">Add</a> and then <a id="addnew2" href="">Add</a> etc?

Thanks for your help.

Dave

Comment: I am still trying to get this going. I wonder, can you clarify what you mean by ready handler. I am not a jquery expert by any means so I am not familiar with this term. I am sorry but I really do not understand what you are saying I need to do here. If I move the currently embedded script to an external file ( I am not too sure why moving it to an external file makes a difference here), I need to pass a call to this function from various forms on the page via what: an onclick="bindLink('addNew2')" type of call?

Dave

Comment: By ready handler, I mean: $.ready(function() {...}) or $(function() {...}))
These allow you to have function() {...} run when the document is finish loading.  Your original/big code snippet has everything within a ready handler.